# How to move the data and log location in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ES cluster setup with 3 master and 2 data node and running properly. I want to change one of the data node data and log location from local to external disk

In my current YAML file
path.data: /opt/elasticsearch/data
path.logs: /opt/logs/elasticsearch

Now I added  2 external disk to my server to store data/logs and would like to change the location to the new drives

I have added the new disk. What  is correct process to point ES data/log to the new disk

The data on this node can be deleted as this is a dev env.

Could I just stop the ES on this server
delete the info in the current data and log folder
mount the new drive to the same mount point and restart the cluster

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the settings in YAML file and restart the elasticsearch service, it should work for you. There is no automatic reload when you change any YAML configuration.

Steps :

1. change Path in YAML
2. Restart the service

Comment: I tried it and ES did not restart and I could not access the error . currently both data and log  folder are in a directory  /opt/data and opt/log which is a path on the physical machine.
The external drive now has  the same path  (opt/data and opt/log)so no changes where needed in the YAML. So, ES did not start. Don't I have to remove the original folders since local and external is same path

Comment: yes, you need to move the data from the old mount to the new one, or Elasticsearch will think it's starting a brand new node